# Laravel artisan command stops after some time

Tags: php, apache, laravel, laravel-artisan

I am using laravel 5.1 and want to update mysql table which has nearly 0.2 million rows. It updates nearly 25000 rows and after that it does not. It takes almost 1 and half hour to update this.

Any Suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

There are few things you want to check for first.

- What errors you get in your php error logs (timeout errors, out of memory errors, etc...)
- What errors you get in your mysql error logs
- Is your kernel killing long running processes (such as in [extreme resource starvation](http://lwn.net/Articles/317814/))

If the script stops updating consistently at the same place, for example, it might be an error in your SQL at that particular statement. So make sure you are checking any errors returned by mysql to PHP (see the manual for handling errors in [PDO](http://php.net/pdo.error-handling) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli.error)).

If you're running 200K different SQL queries through PHP, one at a time, it's bound to be slow because you're going to hit the SQL parser, query execution, and result fetching step at each query. There are some faster alternatives to this like [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html), for example, which bypasses the entire parser and query execution step in MySQL allowing you to directly write to the database object file from a CSV. This is useful for loading large amounts data into your database at once, really fast.

Comment: Initially it updates 6-7 rows per second and speed reduces continuously and it goes to almost zero.

Answer (score 0):

You check your error logs.I think , you said 25000 raw are update well and after that  stop. It may be cause some ,database  row pass error when it update . if you can check update table  part by part, you can verify it .

E.g: First update 1-2000 , and next 2000-40000. when update 20000-250000 range only pass error it mean your program is ok and  db entry  pass error.but block wise ok , when increase the load.it can help to you test your program can handle load. This is some kind of testing methods.

your program may be slow because there are huge collection of data ,and it also depend your computer or server or developing environment performance. try re-factors or optimize your codes improve performance.you also try non-relation database (mongodb) some time , it may be give you good time when handle large number of data. I think this may be help to you solve your trouble.

Comment: Initially it updates 6-7 rows per second and speed reduces continuously and it goes to almost zero.